# Photomos relays connected in Parallel?

Tags: relay, parallel

I have a question about PhotoMOS relays like TLP3546A. Is it possible to connect two of these relays in parallel to increase Load current (upto 6A)??
I know there might be issues with Turn On and Turn OFF time

Answer (score -1):

[image]

The turn on time between 0.8 and 5 milliseconds is a large variety. I would say this is unsuitable for parallel operation unless you perform further binning.

Worst case you can run most current trough one module for ~4 ms.
You can limit this to ~2 milliseconds by increasing led drive.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that putting the two LEDs in series would be preferred over putting them in parallel here?

Comment: Under absolute maximum ratings it says that it supports pulsed current of 10.5A (t=100ms, duty=1/10).

Comment: @Jeroen3 I measured Turn ON time its 240us and Turn OFF time its 120us. I think with this timings its possible to connect them in parallel

Answer (score -1):

Don't parallel since the switching times can be too different.

Instead, use the optocoupler to drive a bigger transistor...or electromechanical relay. There's not much using both an optocoupler and a relay though since the relay already provides isolation so you could just use the relay directly (though you may need a drive transistor if your drive source cannot source enough current).

Comment: Under absolute maximum ratings it says that it supports pulsed current of 10.5A (t=100ms, duty=1/10).